# SQL Server Difference between CPU and CPU_TIME

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In MS SQL Server 2014, what is the difference between `sys.dm_exec_requests.cpu_time` and `master.dbo.sysprocesses.cpu`? I see that sometimes the two values are the same and other times the value are different. When should the values be different?

The following query retrieves both values.

```
SELECT 
      req.cpu_time
    , sp.cpu
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses sp ON req.session_id = sp.spid
```

Here are examples from my server.

[image: cpu vs. cpu_time]

Comment: Why are you looking at sysprocesses? This is a *deprecated* system view that is only there for backward compatibility.

Comment: I want to understand the difference between the statistics in `sysprocesses` and the DMVs because there are still many online resources that refer to it. I believe it is good to know whether it is possible or desirable to retrieve numbers identical to those in `sysprocesses`.

Comment: Those online resources are out of date, and trying to get identical numbers from two different locations doesn't seem very fruitful to me. Do what you like, of course, but you really should be using the newer views IMHO - sysprocesses and the like were replaced for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I can tell you.

Internally, they use two different ways obtaining the data; `sysprocesses` uses the "legacy" method and `sys.dm_exec_requests` uses a newer method. Unless you have a very pedestrian workload these will generally not be the same.

Overall, I must agree with Aaron and not use `sysprocesses` as it is deprecated. Having said that, either method will get you "close enough" to troubleshoot issues and there shouldn't be such a difference that it hides or masks an issue from your troubleshooting efforts.

Note, this was tagged as `SQL2014` and thus this answer should be considered relevant only for `SQL Server 2014` specifically build `12.00.5538` (SP2 CU3).